# Find the representative matrix for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

can someone help me with this Linear Algebra question:

Consider the linear transformation $f:R^2\rightarrow R^4$ given by:
$$
f\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\3\\14\\1\end{bmatrix}, f\begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-4\\-3\\10\\5\end{bmatrix}
$$

What is the representative matrix for f?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider $e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ the canonical basis. Then:

$$f\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}=1\cdot f(e_1)+3\cdot f(e_2)=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\3\\14\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

And

$$f\begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\end{bmatrix}=-1\cdot f(e_1)+3\cdot f(e_2)=\begin{bmatrix}-4\\-3\\10\\5\end{bmatrix}$$

And once $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the canonical basis then  $f(e_1)$ and $f(e_2)$ are the columns of the matrix.

What you have to do is only solve the above system for $f(e_1)$ and $f(e_2)$.

Can you finish?

Comment: @tonytouch: is it clear?

Comment: Thank you, it's very clear!

Answer (score 1):

Matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-2 & -4\\ 3 & -3\\14 & 10\\ 1 & 5 \\\end{bmatrix}
$$
is from base $B = \lbrace (1, 3), (-1, 3) \rbrace$ to standard base. You can take matrix from standard bese to $B$ and multiple, receiving your matrix. It works like that(let $S$ be standard base and $f$ your function):
$$
f: B \to S, g: S \to B
$$
when you multiple you receive:
$$
h = f \circ g : S \to S
$$

And it's what you want.